# C Checking for EOF

Tags: c

I developed a C program that does addition of integers but the problem I am having with this is that it needs to take input from stdin via input text (not interactive). However after testing I can only get it to work for a single line of input when it should work for multiple, assume this sample input are all in a single input file ((Line 1) 123+456= (Line 2) 999999999+1= ).

I think it has to do with EOF and it should go through and repeat until finished. I tried putting an EOF in the first while loop but the output is very different than what it should be. The input format has to stay the same and cannot be changed. Is there anyway I can get it to do operations until the end of input file?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    char a[100], b[100], array[101];
    int n = 0;
//It should scan through everyrthing then exit and it think start arround HERE
        while ((c = (char) getchar()) != '=') { 
        array[n] = c;
        putchar(c);
        n++;
    }
    printf("=\n");
    array[n] = '\0';
    int n1 = 0, n2 = -1;
    while (n1 + n2 < n) { //Splits the array into two separate char arrays
        if (array[n1] == '+') {
            n2 = 0;
            n1 += 1;
        }
        if (n2 == -1) {
            a[n1] = array[n1];
            n1++;
        } else {
            b[n2] = array[n1 + n2];
            n2++;
        }
    }
    n1--;
    a[n1] = b[n2] = '\0';
    int i = 0, z = 0, p = 0;
    char array2[101];
    bool val = false;
    while (n1 > 0 || n2 > 0) { //Addition Calculation
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        if (n1 > 0)
            x = a[n1 - 1] - '0';

        if (n2 > 0)
            y = b[n2 - 1] - '0';
        z = x + y;

        if (val)
            z = z + p;

        if (z > 9) {
            p = z % 10;
            array2[i++] = (char) (p + '0');
            p = z / 10;
            val = true;

        } else {
            array2[i++] = (char) (z + '0');
            val = false;
        }
        n1--;
        n2--;
    }
    if (val) {
        array2[i++] = (char) (p + '0');
        array2[i] = '\0';
    }

    for (n = i - 1; n >= 0; n--) { //Print Result
        printf("%c", array2[n]);
    }
    printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you read `int`s using `scanf()` when you want `int`s? `while ((c = (char) getchar()) != '=')` is why your code only processes the first line.

Comment: I needed to find a way to split the characters between input and exit once it reaches = unless it can be done with scanf and still work the same. getchar just seemed easier since it reads character by character.

Comment: You have to get rid of the misconception that you need to read single chars in the first place. You want numbers? Read numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) what you want is a 4-liner:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    char op, ch;
    while (scanf(" %d %c %d %c", &a, &op, &b, &ch) == 4 && op == '+' && ch == '=')
        printf("%d+%d=%d\n", a, b, a + b);
}
```